# Change Background Color Of Selected Item In ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView, I would like that each time i select an item in the listview, the background color changes to grey. If I select another element I want previous elements background to revert to white and the new item's background to be highlighted in grey

Comment: In Android, "select" with a `ListView` specifically means "use the up/down arrow keys, D-pad buttons, trackball, etc. to move a highlight bar". Is that what you mean by "select" in your question?

Comment: When I say select, I mean that the Selected Item's background colour is grey or the background is highlighted in grey

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953285/android-listview-item-background-change

Comment: That does not answer my question. "Select" (through a 5-way navigation device, like a D-pad) is different than "tap" (through the touchscreen) or "click" (which can be done by either input method). In your question, you used the verb "select". Do you really mean that you are interested solely in the use of a 5-way navigation input device? Or do you really mean "click"?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't specific. I mean on the onclick

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816813/circle-button-in-android) and instead of button you use it in your listview

Comment: To have a `ListView` row stay highlighted after a click, you can use the "activated" pattern. Set up a `StateListDrawable` with a `android:state_activated="true"` state as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26991860/115145, use that as the row background, and set `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` on the `ListView`.

Comment: I used the code below but the listview background is not changing colour  :<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- State when a row is being pressed, but hasn't yet been activated (finger down) -->
<item android:drawable="@color/app_primary_color_light" android:state_pressed="true" />

<!-- Used when the view is "activated". -->
<item android:drawable="@color/app_primary_color" android:state_activated="true" />

<!-- Default, "just hangin' out" state. -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /></selector>

Comment: Check this accepted post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359679/highlight-the-selected-textview-in-different-colour/28361532#28361532), and just change `TextView` to be your item `convertView`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want list items to change background color based on selection, that sounds like basic selector functionality. Create a selector xml file and set it as the background in your row xml.

Something like:

```
 < selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    < item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myGreyColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    < item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myGreyColor" android:state_selected="true"/>
    < item android:drawable="@android:drawable/myWhiteColor"/>
    < /selector>
```